# Need some help fix a unknown issue?

Tags: html, css

I Recently added a comment box on my website under "Guestbook", and now the site is kind screwed. Altough i tryed to remove the comment box but the problem is still there.

And i kindly ask you guys to help me solve this problem.

Website: http://swipper.org

The issue is that the website is way to wide, but i haven't configured it to be more than 100%, and im pretty sure 100% only is the regular screen size.

Please, Leave a answer if you have any idea. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but that's just lazy. What about looking back over the changes you made in source control? You do have source control don't you?

Comment: Tagged with "php, html, css"! How can a display-problem have anything to with PHP?

Comment: Yes, i have source control. But the problem is that didnt do any changes.

Answer (score 2):

1. you don't use a css reset => `body` tag has some extra margins
2. if you have an element that is 100% width and you add borders, the width will be 100%+2px (or whatever border is). However, a block element has 100% by default, so you don't need to specify.
3. `overflow:hidden` for the `#sidebar` will do some magic, but you should apply 1 & 2.

Comment: So, i should make the width 98% instead? will that be a good change?

Comment: unless you have `border:1%`. Don't mix percents with pixels ;)

Answer (score 0):

---

The problem is with the iframe (facebook)- if you remove that the footer won't expand so far.

You should really get a tool like Firebug for development, it can show you where the boundaries of your elements are to see what is throwing out your design.

Good luck with your site.

Comment: It might be. I Think it may been becuse i had z-index:auto; set for body. I Used to use firebug, but i dont use firefox anymore..But i might go back to it for developing reasons.

Comment: Nope, z-index isn't related to widths so it's not relevant.